# How can I SET the value for a variable in a Stored Procedure depending on outcome?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How can I SET the value for a variable within a Stored Procedure depending on the coutcome?

## Example:

The following MySQL-Statement puts the value "X" into variable `check`:

```
SET check := ( SELECT `column2`
FROM `table` 
WHERE `column2` = 'X'
ORDER BY `column1date` ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

But sometimes `table` has no 'X'-Values. In this case, variable `check` should get value "A". How can I SET value "A" in cases when SELECT-Statement returns NULL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET check := IFNULL((SELECT column2 ...), 'A');
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
SET check := 'A';

SELECT column2 INTO check
FROM `table` 
WHERE `column2` = 'X'
ORDER BY `column1date` ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```